# inserting text and separating before placing into MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

i am wanting to create a function by where a client can upload voucher codes via a textarea (i.e. copy and paste) and once form submits, the coding will extract each code and place it in the database with its own id.

code example would be

GBVVVVVVV

HGBBBBBBB

JKKKKKKKK

etc

Comment: Have you tried reading the fantastic php manual? http://php.net/manual is your place... Look for $_POST variable and mysql functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$vouchers = explode("\n", $textfield);
```

which puts each line of the variable $textfield into an array called $vouchers.

you could then loop through all items of the array like so:

```
foreach ($vouchers as &$value) {
    // put your mysql insert here
}
```

Comment: This causes multiple SQL queries which can be slow and problematic. Take a look at my answer to see how to combine everything into one statement.

Answer (score 0):

You would make a SQL statement like so:

```
// Replace "<table name>" with the name of your table.
// This sets up the first part of the SQL statement. This should look very
// familiar if you have used any flavor of SQL.
$query = 'INSERT INTO <table name> VALUES ';
$is_first = true;

// Loop through each line.
// We assume '\n' is the line separator.
// You will need to replace "<textarea name>" with the proper value.
foreach (explode('\n', $_POST['<textarea name>']) as &$voucher) {
    // This determines whether or not we need a comma to separate multiple
    // records. See note below.
    if ($is_first) $is_first = false; else $query .= ', ';
    // This can be unfamiliar to some who are somewhat familiar with SQL. You can
    // insert more than one record with just one query.
    // Note that we escape the $voucher variable to prevent SQL injections.
    $query .= '(' . mysql_real_escape($voucher) . ')';
}
```

Then, send it off like a normal SQL statement via PHP. Note that this assumes you are using the post method. Also, this may have bugs in it. I have not tested it at all but it will definitely lead you in the right direction.